# Python: 'ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar' when looping over rows in pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to loop over the rows of a DataFrame, in my case to calculate strength ratings for a number of sports teams.

The DataFrame columns `'home_elo'` and `'away_elo'` contain the pre-match strength rating (ELO score) of the teams involved and are updated in the row of the next home / away match after the match (each team has two strength ratings at any point in time, for home and away games), with what `update_elo(a,b,c)` returns.

The respective code snippet looks as follows:

```
for index in df.index:

    counter = counter + 1
    # Calculation of post-match ELO scores for home and away teams
    if df.at[index,'updated'] == 2: # Update next match ELO scores if not yet updated but pre-match ELO scores available

        try:
            all_home_fixtures = df.date_rank[df['localteam_id'] == df.at[index,'localteam_id']]
            next_home_fixture = all_home_fixtures[all_home_fixtures > df.at[index,'date_rank']].min()
            next_home_index = df[(df['date_rank'] == next_home_fixture) & (df['localteam_id'] == df.at[index,'localteam_id'])].index.item()
        except ValueError:
            print('ERROR 1 at' + str(index))
            df.at[index,'updated'] = 4

        try:
            all_away_fixtures = df.date_rank[df['visitorteam_id'] == df.at[index,'visitorteam_id']]
            next_away_fixture = all_away_fixtures[all_away_fixtures > df.at[index,'date_rank']].min()
            next_away_index = df[(df['date_rank'] == next_away_fixture) & (df['visitorteam_id'] == df.at[index,'visitorteam_id'])].index.item()
        except ValueError:
            print('ERROR 2 at' + str(index))
            df.at[index,'updated'] = 4

        # print('Current: ' + str(df.at[index,'fixture_id']) + '; Followed by: ' + str(next_home_fixture))
        # print('Current date rank: ' + str(df.at[index,'date']) + ' ' + str(df.at[index,'date_rank']) + '; Next home date rank: ' + str(df.at[next_home_index,'date_rank']) + '; Next away date rank: ' + str(df.at[next_away_index,'date_rank']))

        df.at[next_home_index, 'home_elo'] = update_elo(df.at[index,'home_elo'],df.at[index,'away_elo'],df.at[index,'actual_score'])
        df.at[next_away_index, 'away_elo'] = update_elo(df.at[index,'away_elo'],df.at[index,'home_elo'],1 - df.at[index,'actual_score']) # Swap function inputs for away team


        df.at[next_home_index, 'updated'] = df.at[next_home_index, 'updated'] + 1
        df.at[next_away_index, 'updated'] = df.at[next_away_index, 'updated'] + 1

        df.at[index,'updated'] = 3
```

The code works fine for the first couple of rows. I then, however, encounter errors, always for the same rows, even though I cannot see how the rows would differ from others.

1. If I do not handle the `ValueError` as shown above, I receive the error message `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar` for the first time after about 250 rows.
2. If I do handle the `ValueError` as shown above, I capture four such errors, two for each of the error-handling blocks (the code works fine otherwise), but the code stops updating any further strength ratings after about 18% of all rows, without throwing any error message.

I would very much appreciate it if you could help me (a) understand what causes the error and (b) how to handle them.

Since this is my first post on StackOverflow, I am not yet fully aware of the common posting practices of the forum. Please let me know if there is anything I can improve about my post.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which line specifically causes the error?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the first line in the `try...except` block. Have you checked that all of your indexes are unique (which seems to be an assumption of your code)? Some of those `df.at[index...` calls may be returning multiple values if you have an index that is repeated. Try running `df.index.nunique() == df.index.shape[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.Series.item` requires at least one item in the Series to return a scalar. If:

```
df[(df['date_rank'] == next_home_fixture) & (df['localteam_id'] == df.at[index,'localteam_id'])]
```

is a Series with length 0, then the `.index.item()` will throw a ValueError.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! If I am not mistaken, that shouldn't be the problem, though. The line you referenced returns (and is supposed to return) a Series containing all home game dates of the respective team. The subsequently calculated `next_home_fixture` then contains only one element, which is the game date of the next home game.

Comment: `df.index.nunique() == df.index.shape[0]` returns `True` so that does not seem to be the problem

Comment: What line is the error on? How many items does `df[(df['date_rank'] == next_home_fixture) & (df['localteam_id'] == df.at[index,'localteam_id'])].index` return for the iterations where there's an error?

Comment: Thank you, good call! The error is on the line `next_home_index = df[(df['date_rank'] == next_home_fixture) & (df['localteam_id'] == df.at[index,'localteam_id'])].index.item()` due to `df[(df['date_rank'] == next_home_fixture) & (df['localteam_id'] == df.at[index,'localteam_id'])].index` returning zero elements despite expecting one

Answer (score 18):

FYI,

You will get similar error if you are applying `.item` to a numpy array.

You can solve it with `.tolist()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you have more than 1 item in the series/dataframe that you are doing the .index on:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.item.html